# getOption not working, constant error

Tags: java, methods, printing, shapes

I am trying to move on in my code and I am getting an error that I don't know how to fix.
The code gets to the point where it asks me for the options, then when I type, I'd like it to print 'this is letter S' or 'this is letter T' based on the input entered by the user. Pls keep in mind two things. 1) I need to use the "char getOption()" method and 2) I am new to this, so bear with me on this. The error I am getting is:

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class shapes {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      displayWelcome();
      displayMenu();
      char resp = getOption();  
         if( resp == 'S' )            
            System.out.println("This is letter S");

         else if( resp == 'T' )
            System.out.println("This is letter T");

   }      

   public static void displayWelcome() {

      System.out.println("WELCOME TO THE SHAPE PRINTER!");
      System.out.println("-----------------------------");

   }


   public static void displayMenu() {

      System.out.println("Options: ");
      System.out.println("  S)quare");
      System.out.println("  H) Shape");
      System.out.println("  T)riangle"); 
      System.out.println("  X) Shape");
      System.out.println("  Q)uit");

   }


   public static char getOption() {

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

         input.nextInt();
         char c = input.next().charAt(0);
            return c;

   }
```

}

//Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
//    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864) 
//  at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485) 
//  at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117) 
//  at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076) 
//  at shapes.getOption(shapes.java:60) 
//  at shapes.main(shapes.java:27)

Comment: Any reason for this line          input.nextInt();
?

Comment: I was told I must clear the buffer between Scanners of char/Strings and Int/Doubles

Comment: nextInt waits for an int input and i don't think it clears any kind of buffer. Try to remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no real need of

```
input.nextInt();
```

in your code. Due to this you code execution will request for two  user inputs instead of one. Just remove this and you should be good.